# Need Image in Carousel and Modal to be Opacity 1, while everything else is transparent

Tags: css, reactjs, modal-dialog, carousel, opacity

React css styling question. I have a bootstrap 5 modal component as a parent and a carousel as a child. I am trying to have the modal and carousel transparent while the image in the carousel having full opacity 1. I have tried background color, background image, and change the opacity individual to get my desired outcome but no success.
My biggest issue is that the child component inherits the opacity of the parent as it's initial opacity( 100%(opacity:1)).
for example:
parent element has an opacity of 50%
and child element has an opacity of 100%.
actual opacity of of child element is 50% (100% of 50%).
I would like the child element to be 100%.
Thanks!

Below is my simplified code:

```
    <Modal
             show={modal}
             onHide={handleModalClose}
             fullscreen={true}
             id="modalReactBootstrap"
            >
<Modal.Header id="modalHeader" 
closeButton
></Modal.Header>
<Modal.Body id="modalBody">
                <Carousel>
  <Carousel.Item className="carousel-item">
              <img
                className="imgCarousel"
                src={"https://imagew.com/images/animation_old/anim5.jpg"}
                alt="First slide"
              />
            </Carousel.Item>
            
                </Carousel>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening this question, just to share the answer if anyone searches for the same thing.
The class from react-bootstrap's Modal that allowed for my images in the carousel to have 100% opacity while the rest of the background was partially transparent was "modal-content". I was able to have a working background-color style in the "modal-content" class in order to make it work as desired.